# Server response(IIS7) does not reach client on operations running > ~4+ minutes

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

IIS 7 Tracing shows that request was process successfully:
GENERAL_REQUEST_END BytesSent="767", BytesReceived="5697", HttpStatus="200", HttpSubStatus="0"

But Fiddler(firebug, etc) does not show any response being received.

Keep-Alive header is enabled on IIS.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a client requests something don't mean it sticks around for the answer. I'd up the client app's timeouts if possible and see if that works.

Comment: well, i thought clients(IE8, FF) wait for at least an hour with default settings. Also, Fiddler does not see anything coming in.

Comment: 60 seconds not 60 minutes . . .

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050:
Internet Explorer 4.0 and Internet Explorer 4.01 5 minutes
Internet Explorer 5.x and Internet Explorer 6.x 60 minutes
Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8 60 minutes